# substr[0] not working, returning different characters to echoed string

Tags: php, xml, post

I am using wp_remote_post to post some information to an API like so...

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $validation_url, array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'timeout' => 45,
                    'redirection' => 5,
                    'httpversion' => '1.0',
                    'blocking' => true,
                    'headers' => array(),
                    'body' => $fields,
                    'cookies' => array()
                    )
                    );
```

If I then do this...

```
$validationresponse = $response['body'];
echo $validationresponse;
```

Then it correctly returns the content of $response['body'] which looks like this....

```
100Successfull Validation
```

but if I then try and do this...

```
echo substr($validationresponse, 1);
```

To return the first character then it doesn't work, instead it returns this...

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Am I doing something wrong, can anyone suggest whats happening?

Comment: String are 0-indexed so its : substr($str, 0, 1) for the first char. Keep in mind that a string is actualy an array of chars. U could do $str[0] as well

Comment: `$validationresponse` doesn't equal `100Successfull Validation`. There's a bunch of XML in there that you're not seeing. Don't echo the variable, but use `var_dump`, wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags if you like, you'll see the XML is there.

Comment: Or `echo`, then in your browser, "View Source".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just substract first character go with:

```
echo $validationresponse[0];
```

---

For your code to work (it returns rest of string starting at second character) you should first check if `$validationresponse` has length of 2 or more characters. Also, try to var_dump() (use var_dump() instead of print_r() as var_dump shows NULLs and stuff) result instead of echoeing it as reference says:

```
Returns the extracted part of string; or FALSE on failure, or an empty string.
```

Also, post any errors if you got any.

Comment: The first parts does not actualy applies to the OP's problem, he just sees to much text but it's not to wrong mention

Comment: My point isn't that it is not returning the first character, its that it is not returning the correct character.  Instead of the expected result it is returning characters from something that starts <?xml

Comment: @DarkBee i redesigned my answer for better organization :D;;; fightstarr20: edit your post and show us what you WANT to get from WHAT string and what you actually GET :P

Comment: Hmm, I might have an idea, but please post result of `var_dump($validationresponse);`, ok?

Comment: var_dump gives me string(177) " 100Successfull Validation"

Comment: as you see, length of the string is 177. Add `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` before var_dump and you will see full string. That will tell you how it looks and why you get what you get

Comment: Thanks for that, I can now see it is huge!  Why is this happening though?  When I echo $validationresponse it doesn't give me this?

Comment: It does. But output is XML, and XML is somehow related to HTML (or more to XHTML), so your browser just hide every tags. You can use header `Content-Type` or just open your source code. XML is treacherous :P

Comment: I understand now, thanks for explaining.  So it is actually returning the full result but my browser is hiding it.

Comment: Yes, just like with HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

As you've written it - `echo substr($validationresponse, 1);` - would return the rest of the string starting with the second character. If you want a single character you would use - `echo substr($validationresponse, 1, 1);`. See http://php.net/substr. Is that the situation you see?

Comment: He wants the first character, not the 2nd tho :)

Comment: Oops! My mistake. Then you would use `echo substr($validationresponse, 0, 1);`. It should return false on failure as well. Must learn to read more carefully. :)